# How to search a single id from two columns in the same table efficiently?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**name**: first_name, last_name, uid

**name_reference**: name_uid_in, name_uid_out

I need to search for people who have some relation to the person who is searched (in this case Anderson). Anderson wrote down that he knows person A, B, C. So in the "name_reference" table, there will be 3 entries with Anderson's uid for name_uid_in and A, B and C's uid's for name_uid_out.

A problem arises when person D comes. Anderson does not know person D, but person D knows Anderson. Now if I search Anderson's uid, person D won't be included in the output; even though he has a relation to Anderson.

The first query below only searches for Anderson's uid in the name_uid_in column, but I need it to also search for Anderson's uid in the name_uid_out column. Is there a way to search both columns without having to search for Anderson's uid a second time like in the second query? The database is going to become fairly large, so I need person's A, B, C and D to be returned in an efficient time.

**First Query**

`SELECT z.first_name, z.last_name, z.uid
        FROM name as z
        WHERE z.uid IN (
            SELECT y.name_uid_out as uid
            FROM name_reference as y
            WHERE name_uid_in in (
                SELECT uid
                FROM name
                WHERE last_name="Anderson")
                )`

**Second Query**

```
`SELECT z.first_name, z.last_name, z.uid
    FROM name as z
    WHERE z.uid IN (
        SELECT y.name_uid_out as uid
        FROM name_reference as y
        WHERE name_uid_in in (
            SELECT uid
            FROM name
            WHERE last_name="Anderson" )
    ) 
    OR uid in (
        SELECT name_uid_in
        FROM name_reference
        WHERE name_uid_out in (
             SELECT uid
             FROM name
             WHERE last_name="Anderson" )
    )`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join query with two join clauses. It will be easier to manage.

1. Join table name and name_reference on uid=name_uid_in
2. In the same query use a second join with name_reference on uid = name_uid_out
3. Use a where clause where uid = "ANDERSON"

   SELECT z.first_name, z.last_name, z.uid
       FROM name as z 
   INNER JOIN 
    name_reference as y 
   ON 
   z.uid = y.name_uid_out
   INNER JOIN 
   name_reference as x 
   ON 
   z.uid = x.name_uid_in
   WHERE
   z.last_name="Anderson"

Also, in the select clause, you can use aliases to see the respective output from the tables... For example,
Select z.uid, y.name_uid_in, z.name_uid_out etc to validate the query output.

P.S:- I do not have an SQL editor on my machine, please let me know if it suffices your purpose. If it does not, may be we can tweak it a bit to get the actual output.